# Zurb Foundation: Block Grid refresh

Tags: zurb-foundation

Assuming I have 10 blocks in a [Foundation "Block Grid"](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) (where these blocks are equally spaced by the Block Grid) in 3 columns. That gives me 3 rows of 3 blocks and 1 row of a single block.

If I dynamically add a class with `display:none` to, let's say, first block what I would get is still the same 4 rows with a hole in place of block number 1.

Is there a way to force it to rearrange the blocks as if it had started with 9 originally where you would get 3 rows of 3 blocks?

### EDIT:

A little later after my initial post it occurred to me to conduct a test and it looks like a bug in Block Grid: I included a `display:none` class to an LI within UL that is controlled by Block Grid in the HTML code from the beginning and sure enough the block that is not supposed to be displayed affects the layout!

It looks like Foundation counts the LI that are coded within the UL without considering their display properties. In the example above if I set the first block (LI) to `display:none` I still get 4 rows with first row having only 2 blocks showing!

Comment: The only way currently to achieve this would be to completely remove the `li`: http://codeply.com/go/qiZ4JZYSRk

Comment: @Skelly, thanks for the suggestion, but it is not an option in my case as I would need the elements to be displayed later when needed and removing them from the DOM isn't going to work. However, I learned - from your input about jQuery `remove()`  - and `detach()` -  that I didn't know before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further search I found that Foundation applies `clear:both` to all n+1th elements in the Block Grid regardless of the element's visibility. However, if all the elements in the grid are of equal size clearing is not going to change anything.

In my case, luckily, all the elements are of the same size so by removing `clear:both` from the CSS (or overriding it with `clear:none !important;`) solves my case. However, this is not a solution if the elements are not of the same size. I also found [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/23759-hidden-elements-in-block-grid) which is practically the same issue.